# Django channel occasionally gets error "cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async"

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

My project recently added django channel for websocket and layer:

```
Django=3.2.6
Channel=3.0.4
channels-redis="3.3.0"
gevent=21.8.0
gunicorn=20.1.0
```

Gunicorn and daphne run WSGI and ASGI separately, Nginx proxy the traffic to WSGI or ASGI.  It is part of supervisord config

```
[program:myproj]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py myproj.wsgi

[fcgi-program:myproj_channel]
socket=tcp://0.0.0.0:8002
directory=/opt/www/myproj

command=daphne -u /var/run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers myproj.asgi:application
```

In my production environment, it has less 0.1%  chances to get  `cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async`. These errors are not from ASGI(daphne) but from normal WSGI(Gunicorn) requests, they didn't occur in same piece of code but the root cause is a database query.

For example, this is in a database query:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
   return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
   return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
   response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
   self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
   raise exc
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
   response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/www/myproj/myproj/services/member_service.py", line 275, in _wrapped_view
   return view_func(api_view, request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/www/myproj/myproj/api/restful/form.py", line 108, in get
   published_form = PublishedForm.objects.get_latest_published_for_form(form_identifier, try_master_form=False)
 File "/opt/www/myproj/myproj/webform/models.py", line 44, in get_latest_published_for_form
   return self.filter(form_case__identifier=form_identifier, form_case__form_state=FORM_STATE_PUBLISHED).latest('version')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 670, in latest
   return self.reverse()._earliest(*fields)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 664, in _earliest
   return obj.get()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
   num = len(clone)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
   self._fetch_all()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
   self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
   results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1173, in execute_sql
   cursor = self.connection.cursor()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
   raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
```

This is on session save

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
   response = self.process_response(request, response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 61, in process_response
   request.session.save()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 81, in save
   return self.create()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 51, in create
   self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 196, in _get_new_session_key
   if not self.exists(session_key):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 47, in exists
   return self.model.objects.filter(session_key=session_key).exists()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in exists
   return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 552, in has_results
   return compiler.has_results()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1145, in has_results
   return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1173, in execute_sql
   cursor = self.connection.cursor()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
   raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
```

This is at session read:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 233, in _get_session
   return self._session_cache

During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/opt/www/myproj/myproj/common/middleware.py", line 24, in __call__
   if 'prefer_locale' not in request.session:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 55, in __contains__
   return key in self._session
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 238, in _get_session
   self._session_cache = self.load()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 43, in load
   s = self._get_session_from_db()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 32, in _get_session_from_db
   return self.model.objects.get(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
   return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
   num = len(clone)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
   self._fetch_all()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
   self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
   results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1173, in execute_sql
   cursor = self.connection.cursor()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
   raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
```

My project doesn't have middleware special for channel - my project runs for years, just recently added channel so no many customised settings for channel.

```
Installed Middleware:
['myproj.common.middleware.SameSiteMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'myproj.common.middleware.MembershipMiddleware',
'myproj.common.middleware.AutoLogoutMiddleware']
```

I am pretty sure these part codes don't have any async methods. Because except websocket code, I only found one place using asyncio (that also in celery task in different docker instance)

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([_get_optimised_file(img, image_uri_map) for img in images_files]))
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

About `_get_optimised_file()` doesn't have any database operation, it checks if a file exists, if not, it sleeps for few seconds and check again.

Just try to understand any circumstance can cause a "async context" created and reuse by other WSGI request?

So far, I only can suspect 2 places. One is in settings.py, before I add both lines (I just disabled ASGI from settings in production env, need to observe if it does any fix)

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproj.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myproj.asgi.application'
```

Second place is that asgi.py, if `AuthMiddlewareStack` breaks something in the sessions? But as my setup already separated ASGI and WSGI...

```
import os

from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import myproj.channel.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myproj.channel.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )),
})
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with almost the same setup. Have you figured it out?